# RestTemplate MalformedByteSequenceException Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, jaxb, xerces, resttemplate

I am trying to load an object from a webservice, using RestTemplate, like this:

```
Menu menu = null;
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
String request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><MenuSync><Header><VendorName>usablehealth</VendorName></Header></MenuSync>";
menu = rest.postForObject("http://localhost:6788/LRequest.cgi", request, Menu.class);
```

This generates an Exception:

> [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:
>   Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.]     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

Seems easy enough, however The XML loaded from the webservice contains no UTF-8 violations. If I use explicit JAXB to unmarchal the object, it works fine.

```
Menu menu = null;
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
String request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><MenuSync><Header><VendorName>usablehealth</VendorName></Header></MenuSync>";
String response = rest.postForObject("http://localhost:6788/LRequest.cgi", request, String.class);
try {
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Menu.class);
  Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
  um.setEventHandler(new CustomValidationEventHandler());
  menu = (Menu) um.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes("UTF-8")));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JAXBException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have not declared the RestTemplate bean in my applicationContext as the marchal/unmarchal implementation should be the default (JAXB?). What is the difference between these solutions?